# 'mysqldump.exe' não encontrado no DBeaver ao exportar banco de dados MySQL

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

Uso o DBeaver para gerenciar minhas bases de dados e preciso exportar uma dessas bases, acontece que ao tentar exportar essa base, em tools/Dump Database, é retornado o seguinte erro:

```
Error executing process
  Utility 'mysqldump.exe' not found in client home 'MySQL Binaries' (C:\Program Files\DBeaver\MySQL Binaries)
```

Estou procurando uma solução mas não encontrei muita coisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O DBeaver não tem o utilitário `mysqldump.exe` disponível. Ele depende de uma instalação de um cliente local do MySQL (ou MariaDB) no seu sistema operacional para ter acesso a esta ferramenta.

Após instalar o banco de dados na sua máquina, é esperado que o DBeaver encontre automaticamente este utilitário de *dump*. Se não ocorrer, basta editar a configuração da conexão, entrar na opção de "Cliente Local" e apontar para o diretório de instalação do banco de dados.

Você pode encontrar mais detalhes e até outras formas diferentes de resolver [nesta issue](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/1361) no GitHub do DBeaver.

Comment: Consegui Dherik , a sua resposta resolveu meu problema muito obrigado !